# what is the difference between those two files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

what's the difference between .scc and .vssscc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of files used by VisualStudio and SourceSafe for source control integration.

For more information look at http://alinconstantin.members.winisp.net/webdocs/scc/SccFiles.htm